# Passing Path as parameters in unix script

Tags: unix

My script has two functions running.
1. checking of file
(it has to check file in path /IIS/Data/arrival)
2. archiving of file
(it has to archive files in path /IIS/Data/archive)

how to pass this paths as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you are using shell script or not. In shell, we can pass path as parameter, shell treats it like string.

```
$ cat ./test.sh 
#!/bin/sh

function check_file {
   file=$1
   ls $file
}

check_file $1
```

the output:

```
$ ./test.sh Downloads/bleachbit-1.10-1.1.fc20.noarch.rpm 
Downloads/bleachbit-1.10-1.1.fc20.noarch.rpm
```